# I download and display Json files using Kivy UrlReguest, but nothing works on android, why?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have 18 Json files on Cloudinary, the files themselves are created using JsonStore from Kivy library. Using the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html), I download these files (The text itself is written in Cyrillic) at the click of a button and display them in Popup, everything works fine on Windows and Linux, but on an Android smartphone, when I click on the button, nothing happens, although the text should be displayed. What am I doing wrong?

[buildozer.spec](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nB1o1QkfgjSeKCQ8TxItyLZKH_FKQy9g)

[My VM](https://github.com/wzphood/kivybits/tree/master/KivyCompleteVM)

The code itself will be given below.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem, MDList
import webbrowser
import os
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from difflib import get_close_matches
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest

KV = '''
<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: "8dp"
    spacing: "8dp"

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "left"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: avatar.height

        Image:
            id: avatar
            size_hint: None, None
            size: "100dp", "100dp"
            source: "icon2.png"

    MDLabel:
        text: "..."
        font_style: "Button"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    MDLabel:
        text: "..."
        font_style: "Caption"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]



Screen:    
# Our button, by clicking on which the text in the label is displayed

    MDIconButton:
        id: image
        icon: ""
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.71}
        width: root.width*0.99
        height:root.height*0.38
        on_release: app.load_json() 

    MDLabel:
        id: info
        text: ""
        halign: 'center'

    MDFloatingActionButton:
        icon: "arrow-left-bold"
        elevation_normal: 10
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.1, "center_y": 0.05}
        on_release: app.previous()

    MDFloatingActionButton:
        elevation_normal: 10
        icon: "arrow-right-bold"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.9, "center_y": 0.05}
        on_release: app.next()

    MDLabel:
        id: page
        text: ''
        text_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
        halign: "center"
        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.05}

    MDLabel:
        id: name
        text: ''
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.51, "center_y": 0.47}

    MDIcon:
        id: review
        halign: "center"
        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.3}
        icon: "thumb-up-outline"
        font_size: "100sp"


    NavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:

            Screen:

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        elevation: 10
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state()]]
                    Widget:


        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            swipe_edge_width: 200

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                id: content_drawer
                ScrollView:
                    DrawerList:
                        padding: "5dp"
                        spacing: "15dp"

                        MDTextField:
                            id: search
                            hint_text: "..."
                            helper_text: "..."
                            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                            max_text_length: 30

                        MDRoundFlatIconButton:
                            icon: "feature-search"
                            text: "Search"
                            width: dp(250)
                            on_release: app.search()

                        # Some Buttons............

# ---------Popup----------
<Popups>:
    ScrollView:
    # Here is our downloaded text   
        MDLabel: 
            id: rev
            text: ''
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            padding_x: 10
            text_size: (root.width, None)
            # font_style: 

    MDFloatingActionButton:
        id: close
        icon: "cancel"
        text: "Close"
        # set size of the button 
        #size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
        # set position of the button   
        pos_hint: {"x":0.95, "y": -0.035}  
        on_release: app.close()

'''


class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass


class DrawerList(ThemableBehavior, MDList):
    pass


class Popups(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super(Popups, self).__init__()
        try:
            self.ids.rev.text = str(text)
        except:
            pass


class TestNavigationDrawer(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        self.im_folder = 'im'
        self.image_arr = []
        self.name_for_urls = []
        self.bad_rev = ['....png']
        self.page = 1

    # Here I take the name of the pictures for display and future use

        for i in os.listdir('im'):
            self.image_arr.append(i)
            self.name_for_urls.append(i.replace(' ', '_').replace('png', 'json'))

        print(self.name_for_urls)

        self.rev_dir = 'revDir'
    # ---url (The text itself is written in Cyrillic) ---
        self.url = 'https://res.cloudinary.com/http-f0433942-xsph-ru/raw/upload/v1589534191/files/folder/'

        self.store = JsonStore('hello.json')

        if os.path.exists('hello.json'):
            pass
        else:
            # put some values
            self.store.put('Theme', name='Light')

        self.color = self.store.get('Theme')['name']

        if self.color == 'Light':
            self.theme_black = False

        else:
            self.theme_black = True

        self.theme_cls.theme_style = self.color
        self.st = ''
        self.show_page_image_name()
        self.rev_show()

    def got_json(self, req, result):
        self.st = ''
        self.root.ids.info.text = 'Start'
        for key, value in result['Review'].items():
            # print('{}: {}'.format(key, value))
            self.st += '{}: {}'.format(key, value)
        print(req)
        self.root.ids.info.text = 'Loaded'
        self.show_popup()

    def load_json(self):
        UrlRequest(self.url + self.name_for_urls[self.page - 1], self.got_json)

    def show_popup(self):

        self.show = Popups(text=str(self.st))

        self.popupWindow = Popup(title="...", content=self.show,
                                 size_hint=(None, None), size=(self.root.width, self.root.height))

        # open popup window
        self.popupWindow.open()

    def close(self):
        print(1)
        self.popupWindow.dismiss()
        # Attach close button press with popup.dismiss action

    def show_page_image_name(self):
        self.root.ids.page.text = str(self.page)
        self.root.ids.image.icon = os.path.join(self.im_folder, self.image_arr[self.page - 1])
        self.root.ids.name.text = self.image_arr[self.page - 1].replace('.png', '')

    def search(self):
        self.get = self.root.ids.search.text
        try:
            if self.get.isdigit() == True:
                if int(self.get) > len(self.image_arr):
                    self.root.ids.search.hint_text = 'Pages Exceeded'
                else:
                    self.root.ids.search.hint_text = 'Search'

                    self.page = int(self.get)
                    self.rev_show()
                    self.show_page_image_name()
            else:
                try:
                    self.root.ids.search.hint_text = 'Search'
                    matches = get_close_matches(self.get, self.image_arr)
                    self.page = self.image_arr.index(matches[0]) + 1
                    print(self.page)
                    self.rev_show()
                    self.show_page_image_name()
                except:
                    self.root.ids.search.hint_text = '...'
        except:
            pass

    def rev_show(self):
        if self.image_arr[self.page - 1] in self.bad_rev:
            self.root.ids.review.icon = 'thumb-down-outline'
        else:
            self.root.ids.review.icon = 'thumb-up-outline'


    def previous(self):
        self.page -= 1
        if self.page == 0:
            self.page = len(self.image_arr)

        self.rev_show()
        self.show_page_image_name()
        print('previous')

    def next(self):
        self.page += 1
        if self.page > len(self.image_arr):
            self.page = 1

        self.rev_show()
        self.show_page_image_name()
        print('next')

    def click(self):
        print('click')


TestNavigationDrawer().run()
```

Comment: Are you using `buildozer`? Have you included internet permissions?

Comment: I use buildozer and I include internet permissions

Comment: You need to request the permission at runtime. See the [documentation](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/#runtime-permissions).

Comment: I add these two lines at the beginning of the file, only replacing WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE by INTERNET. But nothing has changed

Comment: Try doing `import certifi`, then in your UrlRequest pass `ca_file=certifi.where()`, e.g.  `UrlRequest(self.url + self.name_for_urls[self.page - 1], self.got_json)` You'll also need to add certifi to the requirements in your buildozer.spec file

Comment: I added this string  a_file=certifi.where () before UrlRequest (self. url + self. name_for_urls[self.page - 1], self.got_json), and in the spec file added requirements = kivy==1.11.1, kivymd, certifi, but nothing has changed)

Comment: @pikro sorry I had mistyped in my comment, please try `UrlRequest = (self.url + self.name_for_urls[self.page - 1], self.got_json, ca_file = certifi.where())`

Comment: The important part is putting `ca_file=certifi.where()` as a parameter in your UrlRequest

Comment: Write this in the answer, I will mark as resolved